# Windows Forms Application As A Service

Tags: vb.net, startup

I have a problem that I'm trying to figure out.  I was hoping someone might be able to help me.

I have a Windows Forms Application that has a Startup Form when the user starts the program.  This works fine the user wants to use this functionality in interactive mode.

I've been asked to include some code inside this Windows Forms Application and run this code as a service.  This code I am writing has no user interface, it just accepts information from the commandline and processes accordingly.

The tricky part I'm finding is in running my code, that exists inside this Windows Forms Application.

In the Project Properties --> Application --> Startup Form it says Form1 and this is what it is starting when I run the application.

Is there a way to "bypass this" somehow via code or commandline or something so that if I'm running this program from the commandline it will access and run my code without starting up this Form1?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a very different program structure to run as a service.  Best to get started with a *new* project, using the "Windows Service" project template so you'll have a good start on getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set your forms `Opacity` property to 0 and set your forms `ShowInTaskbar`  property as false, then if your program starts normally then when the form loads, set `Opacity` to 100 and `ShowInTaskbar` to true, else leave it as it is.

Example,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Count > 1 Then
        Me.Opacity = 100
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
    Else
        'Code to deal with commandline arguments...
    End If
End Sub
```